# Advanced Level Geometry prob.

Tags: geometry, triangles, angle, quadrilateral

[image]

> $ABCD$ is parallelogram. 
>   $$m(AEB) = 79°$$
>   $$m(ABD) = x$$
>   How do I find $x$? I have tried to find it and got $102°$ but I'm wrong. Thanks for helping.

Comment: "I have tried some ways". In order to help you, you shall write down what you have tried. Maybe it will be found that you were right...

Comment: I'm sorry for that. Its too long can't write here.

Comment: Also can someone help me?

Comment: Are you sure about the angle names in your question wrt the figure?

Comment: Yeah I'm sure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trusting the figure you have
$$\begin{cases}
180° - \frac{1}{2} \widehat C - \frac{2}{3} \widehat D = 79°\\
\widehat C + \widehat D = 180°\\
\end{cases}$$
Can you solve this system? Then $x=\widehat C$.

> $x=114°$